# unable to set autofocus attribute in knockout on a component in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js, autofocus

I am attempting to set focus to the first input using knockout in firefox. I've tried both the autofocus binding. and setting the autofocus attribute. but neither appear to be working in firefox. It does seem to work in edge and ie11 (I can't try chrome here at work as it is blocked.... Don't ask)

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/44/

```
ko.components.register('inquiry-form', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.label = params.label;
    this.value = params.value;
    this.placeholder = params.placeholder;
    this.id = params.id;
    this.maxlength = params.maxlength;
    this.autofocus = params.autofocus;
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(params.autofocus);
  },
  template: '<div class="form-group">\
            <label data-bind="attr: {for: id}"> \
                <span data-bind="text: label"></span>: \
            </label> \
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: value, attr: {id: id, placeholder: placeholder, maxlength: maxlength, autofocus: autofocus}, hasFocus: isSelected" />\
         </div>'
});
```